# Install id3_tag in PHP Ubuntu

Tags: php, php7, source-packages, id3

How can I Install and configure id3_tag package installed from PECL? I already have the package but I don't know how to configure it and where to put it in the file system.

Comment: Please describe more precisely what you have done already and what you want to achieve. Voting to close as unclear in the meantime.

Comment: Have you read through the [ID3 and PECL documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/id3.installation.php)?

Incidentally, looking at the [maintainer package](https://pecl.php.net/package/id3), this is pretty old package. It appears to have been last updated in 2004, and even then it was alpha code.

If it were me, I'd rethink using this package, as the resource ecost of getting it sorted might be significant.